# What are Agile methodologies of project management that work on open source projects?

Tags: project-management

Are there any Agile workflow that a team that don't necessarily have sprints, set hours, with varying amounts of time, that are able to be implemented? Ideally I'd like to be able to contain a minimum viable amount of features after a release, in order to keep releases happening on a regular schedule. At the moment everything stays on bleeding edge, and never gets polished to the stage where a release would work, or stays stuck in a pull request bit rotting.

Comment: I am not sure that a process is what you need... What you might need is to work to diligently handle the PRs, ensure that your code is and stays stable (automated tests and CI) and make a release each time you have a stable base with enough improvements.

Comment: I'm very confused by the down and close votes. There are other questions on this site about appropriate project management techniques.

Comment: Possibly too broad?

Answer (score 2):

I think that open source is irrelevant, but a team distributed by space and time is relevant. Test first would be a good thing to do.

Test first has the attitude that you are never more than a few seconds away from a release. No polishing.

It is not done until it passes all tests.

If you are told it is done, but just needs debugging, then it is not done. This methodology spends over 80% of its time in the debug stage. You never know how much progress you have made, and are always late.

With test first, **when it is done it is done**. With an automated set of tests you can also avoid regressions.

Comment: Open Source is relevant to the *question* but maybe not the answer, it conveys meaning behind a community project, and that it most likely (based on other open source projects) accepts pull requests, volunteer time, volunteer effort etc.